# Calling REST API with JSON response from setlist.fm

Tags: android, api

Anyone ever called the setlist.fm API from Android?  I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest;

        try
        {
            getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            return getResponseEntity.getContent();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
            return null;
        }
```

But I run into 2 issues it seems.  The execute always seems to return correctly with a statusline of 200, but when I try to get the entity the length is -1 even though the response object shows a basichttpentity object was returned.  Also, when I try to call getContent it blows up for some reason with a generic exception.  A sample API call that I'm trying to use is http://api.setlist.fm/rest/0.1/search/setlists.json?artistName=Prince.

Any suggestions would be gladly welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.  It seems that the response coming back from the API is streamed and comes in chunks and I was attempting to grab the entity before it was finished.  I removed this code:

```
HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
return getResponseEntity.getContent();
```

And replaced it with:

```
return EntityUtils.toString(getResponse.getEntity());
```